# How can i apply bootstrap in my website? ASP.NET, C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have design a website which working fine regarding to design in desktop pc/laptop screen,but it's not working well in mobile and tablets devices.I'm using "responsive web design tester" google chorme add one to check this.It's middle contents changes.
How can i apply bootstrap in my website??I just include links of bootstrap or change the whole design.I'm beginner,I don't know how to apply "bootstrap".I have installed "Bootstrap" by using  “Manage NuGet Package". Here is my solution explore snapshot

[image]

Here is my desktop view some content
 [image] 
Here mobile view 
   [image]
Here is my aspx code ,specific part of code in which the content not working well :

```
<section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="title-area">
                        <h2 class="title">About us</h2>
                        <span class="line"></span>
                        <p>
                            UpSkill blends scientifically approved principles of learning and the best quality content to boost personal learning!
                            We aim to be the hub of quality education for personal growth and individual learning for a successful career!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end about -->
    <!--Courses Start Here-->

    <section id="our-team">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="title-area">
                            <h2 class="title">Our Courses</h2>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                            <p>Search Courses as you want to study and Learn from our best Team!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="our-team-content">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!-- Start single Course -->
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="single-team-member">
                                            <div class="team-member-img">
                                                <img src="assets\images\courses\linux.png" alt="linux img">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="team-member-name">

                                                <p style="position: relative; left: 7px; font-size: 25px;">Introduction to Linux </p>

                                                <span style="position:relative; left:7px">CS250</span>

                                            </div>
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--    <div class="team-member-link">
                                  <a class="read-btn wow fadeInUp" href="#"><font color="black"></font></a>
                                </div> -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Start single Course  -->
                                    <!-- Start single Course  -->
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="single-team-member">
                                            <div class="team-member-img">
                                                <img src="assets\images\courses\asp-net.png" alt="asp.net img">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="team-member-name">
                                                <p style="position: relative; left: 7px; font-size: 25px;">Introduction to Asp.net</p>
                                                <span style="position:relative; left:7px">CS250</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<div class="team-member-link">
                                  <a class="read-btn wow fadeInUp" href="#"><font color="black"></font></a>
                                </div>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Start single Course  -->
                                    <!-- Start single Course  -->
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="single-team-member">
                                            <div class="team-member-img">
                                                <img src="assets\images\courses\php.png" alt="php img">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="team-member-name">
                                                <p style="position: relative; left: 7px; font-size: 25px;">Introduction to PHP</p>
                                                <span style="position:relative; left:7px">CS250</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<div class="team-member-link">
                                  <a class="read-btn wow fadeInUp" href="#"><font color="black"></font></a>
                                </div>  -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Start single Course  -->
                                    <!-- Start single Course  -->
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="single-team-member">
                                            <div class="team-member-img">
                                                <img src="assets\images\courses\html.png" alt="html img">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="team-member-name">
                                                <p style="position: relative; left: 7px; font-size: 25px;">Introduction to HTML5</p>
                                                <span style="position:relative; left:7px">CS250</span>
                                            </div>

                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Start single Course member -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <button style="position:relative; left:1170px; color:black; font-size:18px; width:130px; height:60px;">See More</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

"About" and "Our Courses" also working well in mobile devices,but problem with blow code.
Here is my bootstrap.css code :

```
      .container {
      padding-right: .9375rem;
     padding-left: .9375rem;
     margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
     }

     .container::after {
       display: table;
       clear: both;
       content: "";
     }

  @media (min-width: 544px) {
    .container {
     max-width: 576px;
   }
   }

   @media (min-width: 768px) {
   .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
  }

   @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
   max-width: 940px;
  }
 }

  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .container {
   max-width: 1140px;
 }
 }

 .container-fluid {
  padding-right: .9375rem;
  padding-left: .9375rem;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.container-fluid::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

 .row {
  margin-right: -.9375rem;
  margin-left: -.9375rem;
}

  .row::after {
  display: table;
   clear: both;
   content: "";
 }

   .col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3,
  .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, 
 .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9,
  .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, 
 .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, 
 .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, 
  .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12,
 .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, 
 .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6,
 .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9,   
 .col-md-10, .col-md-11,
.col-md-12, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,   .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, 
.col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9,  
 .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12,
 .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3,  
  .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6,
  .col-xl-7,.col-xl-8, .col-xl-9,   
  .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: .9375rem;
   padding-left: .9375rem;
   }

 .col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, 
.col-xs-5, .col-xs-6,    .col-xs-7, 
 .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
 float: left;
 }

.col-xs-1 {
 width: 8.333333%;
  }
 .col-xs-2 {
 width: 16.666667%;
  }

  .col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
  }

 .col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.333333%;
 }

  .col-xs-5 {
 width: 41.666667%;
 }

 .col-xs-6 {
 width: 50%;
}

.col-xs-7 {
 width: 58.333333%;
}

  .col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.666667%;
  }

  .col-xs-9 {
   width: 75%;
  }

  .col-xs-10 {
   width: 83.333333%;
  }

   .col-xs-11 {
   width: 91.666667%;
  }

   .col-xs-12 {
   width: 100%;

  }
```

How can i apply "Bootstrap" on my website?Which works well in every device.
Thanks..

Comment: well 1st go through the bootstrap site, then check what css and .js files must be referenced in your html page. Then begin to build your html using bootstrap classes. A lot of bootstrap comes from using bootstrap classes. E.g. `<div class='col-md-3'></div>`

Comment: I also have bootstrap.css file included in my assets folder and i also used classes and div "col-md-3" but i don't know how can i set,can you help me please,

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit more to bootstrap than just dropping the files in (So you should spend a bit of time learning the basics), but have a look at this section to get your basic html:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

This will link the bootstrap javascript and css. Be sure to add any of your own javascript/css as well.

Then have a look at the overview and grid system at: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

This is how you choose the structure of your site using html as JustLearning mentioned. You'll probably be just putting your images in 1 row spanned across 4 columns.

Comment: My header and footer working fine in bootstrap but issue with some content can u help me ?

Comment: Try just simplifying it to
<div class="container">
<div class="row">{Fill up 12 columns here}</div>
<div class="row">{Fill up 12 columns here}</div>
<div class="row">{Fill up 12 columns here}</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The page looks bootstrapped to me but it depends on whether you meant you want your images to turn into links or made smaller into icons as that will be a new question. Responsive design is about the page fitting into the device and your page appears to fit although the images have been resized. Plus I don't see any MVC or C# or ASP.net so this is straight forward as it looks like you just have a basic HTML5 site. Here is a good link to get you started: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bootstrap.html

Comment: My header and footer working fine in bootstrap but issue with some content can u help me ?

Comment: What content has the issue?